# Replacing multiple values in pandas column at once

Tags: pandas, replace

This is an incredibly basic question but after reading through Stack and the documentation for str.replace, I'm not finding the answer. Trying to drop all of the punctuation in a column. What would be the proper syntax for this?

This works but it's absurd:
`igog['text']=igog['text'].str.replace(",","").str.replace("/","").str.replace(".","").str.replace("\"","").str.replace("?","").str.replace(";","")`

This doesn't:
`igog['text'] = igog['text'].str.replace({","," ","/","",".","","\"","","?","",";",""})`.

Because I keep getting "replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'repl'".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use regular expression `igog['text'].str.replace("[,/.\?;]", "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a simple loop like this:

```
t=",/.\?;"
for i in t:
   igog[text]=igog[text].replace(i,"")
```

or you can use `regex`:

```
igog['text'].str.replace("[,/.\?;]", "")
```

or you can use [re.sub()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
igog['text'] = re.sub('[,/.\?;]', "", igog['text'])
```

or you can define a [translation table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) :

```
igog['text'].translate({ord(ch):' ' for ch in ',/.\?;'})
```