# Cannot substitute with regular expression re library

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to remove all elements that have the form `\x` followed by two numbers. I have created the following regular expression `r'\\x[0-9][0-9]'`. I then test it with the following code:

```
pattern1 = r'\\x[0-9][0-9]'
a = "\x85ciao \x85839"
re.sub(pattern1, "", a)
```

But it is not working as it does not replace anything. The output is in fact the same as string a. What could be causing this behaviour?

I am also having the same issue with replacing `\'` in strings. I would like to remove only the backlash and keep the `'`. How can I do this?

Comment: Two issues: (1) you're not doing anything with the result of `re.sub()` - it doesn't change the original string, it returns a new one; (2) there aren't actually any backslashes or 'x's in `a`, the two `\x85` are *escape sequences* that were converted to a single non-ASCII character when Python compiled the string literal.

Comment: This is an important and commonly misunderstood point, so I want to restate it.  Your string does not contain any backslashes.  That notation is just a convenience for you to write strings.  Your string contains 10 characters, not 16.  Two of the characters happen to be ASCII value 0x85, which is an ellipsis in CP1252.  If you want to get rid of those, use `a.replace('\x85','')`.  Is this Python2 or Python 3?  Where did the strings come from?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67290773/15160601

Comment: This is Python3. I know I can remove them with `a.replace('\x85','')`, the issue though is that there is a lot of different two-digit value combinations of the same problem (e.g. `\x92`, `\x97`, ...) and I am trying to find a way to remove all of them simultaneously, hence the use of regular expression. Is there any way you know of? The strings are S-1 company filings retrieved from the corresponding HTML version of the filing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import re
a = "\x85ciao \x85839"
re.sub('\x85','', a)
```

or simply:

```
a.replace("\x85", "")
```

Comment: Regular expressions are not needed here.  Simple string replace would work fine.